# content and wrapper does not extend properly when content extends

Tags: css, html

I am having a problem with my web page, because I have a wrapper around all element of the page (header,navigation menu and content) when the content expands due to the amount of data to display it would go over the wrapper without pushing it down, but on IE7 it does expand the wrapper.

It is driving me crazy, and I can not figure out why it is doing this.

Sorry for the code, as it may have too many divs, but I dont know any other way to create round corner.

code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
    <link href="greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
    *
    {
        padding:auto;
        margin:auto;
        text-align:center;
        }
    div
    {
        text-align:left;
        display:block;

        }
    </style>

</head>
<body style="">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <!--Main div container-->
<div style="background-image:url('Images2/Content/WrapTop.gif');width:1210px;height:18px;background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-top:10px;" ></div>
<div style="background-image:url('Images2/Content/WrapMid.gif');width:1210px;min-height:900px;display:block;background-repeat:repeat-y;">
<!--Menu container-->
<!--Heading-->
<div style="width:1210px;height:132px;background-image:url('Images2/Heading/Heading.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<div style="width:1046px;height:6px;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
<div style="width:1046px;height:96px;background-image:url('Images2/Heading/tiltle.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
<div style="width:1046px;height:3px;display:block;"></div>
<!--Top Menu-->
<div style="width:1200px;height:25px;text-align:justify;padding-bottom:-10px;">
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;display:block;float:left">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;display:block;float:left">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;display:block;float:left">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;display:block;float:left">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;display:block;float:left">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;display:block;float:left">&#160;</a>
</div>
</div>
<!--Container of menu and subcontainer-->
<div style="width:1212px;min-height:750px;margin-top:60px;margin-left:15px;">
<!--Menu-->
<div style="width:274px;float:left;">
<div style="float:left">
<div style="width:272px;height:39px;background-image:url('Images2/menu/MenuTop.gif');color:White;"><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Electronics" OnClientClick="FindSubCats(560864, 'SearchSubCatsOne');return false;" /></div>
<div id="SearchSubCatsOne" style="width:272px;height:auto;background-image:url('Images2/Menu/menuMid.gif');background-repeat:repeat-y;"></div>
<div style="width:272px;height:14px;background-image:url('Images2/Menu/menuBottom.gif');"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<div style="width:272px;height:39px;background-image:url('Images2/Menu/MenuTop.gif');"></div>
<div id="SearchSubCatsTwo" style="width:272px;height:auto;background-image:url('Images2/Menu/menuMid.gif');background-repeat:repeat-y;"></div>
<div style="width:272px;height:14px;background-image:url('Images2/Menu/menuBottom.gif');"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<div style="width:272px;height:39px;background-image:url('Images2/Menu/MenuTop.gif');"></div>
<div id="SearchSubCatsThree" style="width:272px;height:auto;background-image:url('Images2/Menu/menuMid.gif');background-repeat:repeat-y;"></div>
<div style="width:272px;height:14px;background-image:url('Images2/Menu/menuBottom.gif');"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!--Content Menu-->
<div style="width:802px;float:left;min-height:650px">
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
<div style="width:800px;height:37px;background-image:url('Images2/Content/contentTop.gif');"></div>
<div   style="width:800px;min-height:650px;background-image:url('Images2/Content/contentMid.gif');background-repeat:repeat-y;display:block;">
<div id="Products" style="width:800px;min-height:650px;display:block;"></div>
</div>

<div style="width:800px;height:13px;background-image:url('Images2/Content/contentBottom.gif');"></div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
<div style="background-image:url('Images2/Content/WrapBottom.gif');width:1210px;height:15px;background-repeat:no-repeat;" ></div>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On quick look, it may be caused by the fact that you've got floated divs inside the wrapper which means they'll gladly float outside of it.

As a quick hack, add this as the last element inside your wrapper:

```
<div style="clear: both"></<div>
```

If that solves it, you can add a cleaner "clear: both" solution into your CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for max-width or max-height, and for problems like this, you may want to take a look at overflow settings.

Also, FWIW, This code is going to be very hard for you to maintain if you continue to keep the CSS inline. You should be using classes and IDs with an external CSS file. That way, you can quickly change your entire site's design - plus the information only has to be loaded & cached once by the client browser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the inline style it is temporaly until I get a solid template, and then I will remove all the styling to move it to an external file.